# How to add a collection in Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Hello I am creating a two dimensional array in javascript. the object looks like this.

```
totalCells = [
    lineNumber = 0,
    cells = []
 ];
```

How do I add that to this array ?

Can I do `totalCells.push(1, ['a', 'b', 'c']);`

But this throws me the error : `cells is not defined`

Comment: You seem to be confusing arrays and objects. In JS, arrays have numbered elements, object have named properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying. If you want keys in an array use an object. Then you can do this:

```
var totalCells = {
    lineNumber: 0,
    cells: []
};

// some logic...

totalCells.lineNumber = 1;
totalCells.cells = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

Alternatively, you could have an array of objects which ties the `cells` directly to multiple lineNumbers:

```
var totalCells = [];

// some logic...

totalCells.push({
    lineNumber: 1,
    cells: ['a', 'b', 'c']
});

totalCells.push({
    lineNumber: 2,
    cells: ['x', 'y', 'z']
});
```

Comment: `=` should be `:` in the object literal.

Comment: @Barmar thanks. Copy+paste not always the best way :)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to model your 2 dimensional array would be to use an array of arrays.  e.g.

```
totalCells = [];

totalCells.push(['a','b','c']);
totalCells.push(['d','e','f']);
```

The line number is implicit, for example, in this case, totalCells[0] is the first line, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Rory answer. Use an object

`var totalCells = {}`

Then you can directly add keys/properties:

```
totalCells[1] = ['a','b','c']
totalCells[2] = ['d','e','f']
```

The advantage with this is you can use your object as a Map:

`totalCells[1]` will return `['a','b','c']`

Using u[nderscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/#objects) (or lodash), you can then do fancy manipulations like extract keys, etc....